# Database every row in different div

Tags: javascript, html

I try to make for every row in my database a different div. It only doesn't work when I  try to run it, it gives me only two letters. I checked my PHP and it works correctly.

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest;
request.open('GET' , 'myurl', false);
request.send();
console.log(request);

if (request.status == 0) console.log(request.responseText);

var firstname, lastname;
var obj = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
console.log(obj);

for (var i = 0; i<obj.length; i++){
    firstname = obj[i].Firstname;
    lastname = obj[i].Lastname;

    console.log(firstname,lastname);

    var divElement = document.createElement("div");  
    divElement.id = "myDiv";  

    divElement.className = "myDivClass";  
    divElement.innerHTML = firstname[i] + " " + lastname[i];
    document.body.appendChild(divElement);    
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. I noticed thought that your re-assigning divElement in each iteration of your for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be writing only the elements based on the loop.

Why are you doing

```
 divElement.innerHTML = firstname[i] + " " +  lastname[i];
```

when it needs to be

```
 divElement.innerHTML = firstname + " " +  lastname;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest;
request.open('GET', 'myurl', false);
request.send();
console.log(request);

console.log(request.responseText);
var firstname, lastname;

var obj = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
console.log(obj);

for (var i = 0; i<obj.length; i++) {
  firstname       = obj[i].Firstname;
  lastname        = obj[i].Lastname;

  console.log(firstname,lastname);


  var divElement = document.createElement("div");  
  divElement.id = "myDiv";  

  divElement.className = "myDivClass";  

  divElement.innerHTML = firstname + " " +  lastname;

  document.body.appendChild(divElement);  
}
```

Try this.